# How to smooth a line surface to meet one pixel width?

Tags: matlab, line, smoothing

I have a small problem in smoothing a line surface.

The image is a result of edge detection after sobel processing.

It has an uneven surface, and the unit of bulges is one pixel.

Red circle parts are the bulges.

[image: The result of edge detection after sobel processing.]

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/smooth-contour-data-with-convolution-filter.html

The link I have tried, but the line width was increased too more.

[image: smooth with convolution twice]

I have to get a straight line with **one pixel width**.

How to clear up these bulges?

Many Thanks.

---

**7/21 update:**

Canny method can generate a detected image with one pixel.

The result of Canny edge detection:
[image]

The line was segmented 2 parts, the under part was shifted by one pixel.

I hope the line that can be considered a straight line rather than 2 lines when the line width is within 2~3 pixel.

With Dilate and Erosion, I tried to smooth the line that become a straight line

Canny > Dilate:

[image]

Canny > Dilate > Erosion:

[image]

The result of before and after are the same...

Could anyone give me an idea?

Many Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an approach similar to [Canny edge detection](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html?searchHighlight=canny) could be the solution you are searching for. The Canny edge detector uses non maximum suppression, meaning that the edges are formed only by pixels that have the maximum gradient between their neighbours, resulting in many occasions in one-pixel-width edges.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's very helpful, but the result still not meet the goal. I have updated Canny result on my thread.

Comment: Nice result. What you could do next, is get the endpoints of the line and force them to be on the same column, so as to get a perfect line segment. Using [bwmorph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) you can skeletonise your line, in order to get its endpoints. Then, change the position of one of them and finally draw a line to connect them (you may use [line object function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html)).

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a simple 2-D, black-and-white image, stored as a 0/1 array, and you guarantee there will always be a straight line all the way from top to bottom, then this may help -

```
% recreate scenario
A = zeros(100,50);
A(:,25) = 1;
A([30:40,80:85],24)=1;
A([20:35,70:90],26)=1;
% a rude way
S = sum(A,1);
B = repmat(S==max(S),100,1);
imshow(B)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, your method gives me another thinking to improve my problem.